# MS-Project-2016 XSD Availability?

Tags: ms-project

I'm trying to import an XML generated in MS Project 2016 into another system, but the XSD I have seems to be from an older version. I've only been able to find it for 2007 and 2010. I can probably tweak what I have to account for the differences, but it would be nice to not have to. Are schema definitions for newer versions of Project available somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I'm not sure they exist. I look for updated versions periodically but I haven't come across any yet.

The most recent version I have has the filename `mspdi_pj15.xsd`, and the comment in the file says `Revision date: 2012-07-18`. This was extracted from the [Project 2013 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30435).

One word of warning is that regardless of MS Project version changes, the XSDs don't match what Project actually reads and writes in a few areas. I use the XSD to generate JAXB code as part of [MPXJ](http://www.mpxj.org/), and I've had to make a number of manual revisions to the published XSD to get it work correctly. Unfortunately  I'm not sure that publishing the changes is possible as the original file is copyright Microsoft and doesn't mention redistribution.